# Javascript - passing dynamic recursive PHP value as javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox, dynamic-values

New to javascript. I have a while loop in PHP that looks like this

```
while ($row_voucher=mysql_fetch_row($risultato_query_voucher)) {    //INFO poche righe sotto, date_format da solo non funziona 
        echo "<tr>\n
                <td id=" . $row_voucher[3] ."><input type='checkbox' value='" . $row_voucher[3] . "' onchange='ControllaCodice(this)' id='" . $row_voucher[6] . "'></td>\n
                <td>" . $row_voucher[2] . "</td>\n
                <td>" . $row_voucher[3] . "</td>\n
                <td>" . date_format( new DateTime($row_voucher[4]), 'd/m/Y' ). "</td>\n
                <td>" . date_format( new DateTime($row_voucher[5]), 'd/m/Y' ). "</td>\n
                <td>" . $row_voucher[6] . "</td>\n
              </tr>\n";
      }
```

What i need to do is, when you click on the checkbox, to take the value of the first input type and add it. Since it's a while loop this will generate a table with a lot of checkboxes each one with a different value. So if you for example check 3 checkboxes the javascript I've written should take the 3 values and add it and then print it.
If possible i'd need also to add the value on check and subtract it on uncheck.

Here's the not working javascript code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   function ControllaCodice(this.value){
   window.alert(this.value);
   }
 </script>";
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't pass `this.value`, but `this` to a function which accepts one attribute. The name of the variable *doesn't matter*, only the contents does. Though, you can't accept `this` in the function, it's a reserved variable.

Also, it's not obligatory to use `window.alert`, could be done just with `alert`.

So, the code is:

```
... onchange = "ControllaCodice(this)" ...
```

---

```
function ControllaCodice(c){
   alert(c.value);
}
```

Comment: Even using just (this) doesn't work: it returns an uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token this

Comment: @The `this` is a reserved variable and can't be used. Try my code in the exact form I've provided it.

Comment: I changed the onchange event with 'ControllaCodice(c)' and the function in the same way changing function like

    ControllaCodice(c){
     alert(c.value);
    }

Still when i check a checkbox the error is: Uncaught ReferenceError: c is not defined.

Comment: @The Nope, you must call it with `this`, accept with `c`.

Comment: Ok thank you, i think (hope) i'll be able to handle the add and subtract stuff by myself.

Answer (score 0):

`this.value` is not a valid parameter name, and using the function owner as a parameter is a bad idea. Instead, have it be a normal parameter.

```
function ControllaCodice(input) {
    alert(input.value);
}
```